# XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy - https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/token

Tags: javascript, typescript, cors, onelogin

I am setting up onelogin and I came to this step where I must send one more POST request with the given code from the first GET request (https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code-grant).

They are saying I must send the POST request to this URL https://.onelogin.com/oidc/token and I am sending the request with Angular 7.

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': `Basic <base64 encoded ${environment.clientId}:${environment.clientSecret}`
    });
    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };
    const body = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: code,
      redirect_url: this.getCallbackURL(),
      client_id: environment.clientId,
      client_secret: environment.clientSecret
    };
    return this.httpClient.post('https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/token', body, options).toPromise();
```

But then I get this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/token' from origin 'https://my-site-name.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

NOTE: replaced  with openid-connect-eu as I am in the EU as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript prevents POST calls to other domains at the browser level unless they are expressly permitted by the service (and OneLogin doesn't permit this, for security reasons)

I'll add that doing this authentication flow via Javascript is not considered secure since anyone could intercept the clientID and Secret from your code.

For javascript apps, I'd recommend using the Implicit OIDC flow, which is documented here:

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/id-token

OneLogin also has sample code for this:

https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node/tree/master/2.%20Implicit%20Flow